# The pair library (of the STL) could not be found

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I'm writing a C++ program using iterators. I have a data structure that is a map. I use iterators to loop from the begin to the end of the map and for each element of the map I do something with the key and the value.

So when I want to know the key and the value of a specific element of the map, I use `first()` and `second()` on my iterator.

Like this :

```
#include <map>
#include <pair>

map<unsigned long, int> myMap;
map<unsigned long, int>::const_iterator it;
for(it = myMap.cbegin(); it != myMap.cend(); ++it)
{
    unsigned long key_of_map = it.first();
    int val = it.second();
    cout << "Key is : " << key_of_map << endl << "Value is : " << val << endl;
}
```

When I compile it, it tells me :

> "**../src/myfile.cpp:16:10: fatal error: 'pair' file not found**"

I'm using Eclipse (version Luna), the standard version I downloaded from the official website (I didn't changed anything).

Comment: `<map>` already has `std::pair`. `<utility>` has `std::pair` instead of `<pair>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to

```
 #include <utility>
```

to use [`std::pair<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)